# \Umath doesn't work in LuaLatex and OTF fonts

Tags: luatex, math-fonts

I have tried to change the vertical space in fractions using LuaLaTeX and STIX fonts.

I have used the following commands

```
\Umathfractionnumup\textstyle
\Umathfractiondenomdown\textstyle
\Umathfractionnumvgap\textstyle
\Umathfractiondenomvgap\textstyle
```

But nothing happens. I have also tried incrementing space and decrementing the spaces

```
\Umathfractionnumup\textstyle = 2 ex
\Umathfractiondenomdown\textstyle = 2 ex
\Umathfractionnumvgap\textstyle = 6 pt
\Umathfractiondenomvgap\textstyle = 6 pt
```

and

```
\Umathfractionnumup\textstyle = 0.5 ex
\Umathfractiondenomdown\textstyle = 0.5 ex
\Umathfractionnumvgap\textstyle = 0 pt
\Umathfractiondenomvgap\textstyle = 0 pt
```

and nothing happens. Numerator and denominator stay always fixed.

Thus I have tried with latinmodern-math font and another strnge thing happens.

Using `\setmathfont{latinmodern-math}` the situation is the same as with STIX font. Nothing happens by changing `\Umath` commands.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
%\setmathfont{texgyrepagella-math}
%\setmathfont{STIXTwoMath-Regular.otf}
%\setmathfont{STIX2Math}
\setmathfont{latinmodern-math}
\begin{document}
\Umathfractionnumup\textstyle=10pt
\Umathfractiondenomdown\textstyle=10pt
\Umathfractionnumvgap\textstyle=10pt
\Umathfractiondenomvgap\textstyle=10pt
\Umathfractionnumup\displaystyle=10pt
\Umathfractiondenomdown\displaystyle=10pt
\Umathfractionnumvgap\displaystyle=10pt
\Umathfractiondenomvgap\displaystyle=10pt

Texstyle $\frac12$

displaystyle
$$\frac12$$

\end{document}
```

[image: using \setmathfont]

but if I don't use the \setmathfont{latinmodern-math} command the \Umath commands have effect. The strange is the the font used remain latinmodern-math.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
%\setmathfont{texgyrepagella-math}
%\setmathfont{STIXTwoMath-Regular.otf}
%\setmathfont{STIX2Math}
%\setmathfont{latinmodern-math}
\begin{document}
\Umathfractionnumup\textstyle=10pt
\Umathfractiondenomdown\textstyle=10pt
\Umathfractionnumvgap\textstyle=10pt
\Umathfractiondenomvgap\textstyle=10pt
\Umathfractionnumup\displaystyle=10pt
\Umathfractiondenomdown\displaystyle=10pt
\Umathfractionnumvgap\displaystyle=10pt
\Umathfractiondenomvgap\displaystyle=10pt

Texstyle $\frac12$

displaystyle
$$\frac12$$

\end{document}
```

[image: without \setmathfont]

In the log file the used font is `latinmodern-math`.
Also opening PDF file the font is always the same.

Comment: When I tried `\loadmath{[STIXTwoMath-Regular]}` followed by your set of `\Umath...` commands followed by your `$1\over2$` test followed by `\bye` in OpTeX then all works. I.e. the vertical spaces are in the fractions. It means that the problem is not in the font, not in the LuaTeX, but only in the used macro.

Answer (score 3):

Some things are not fully set up until the first use of math so your settings get undone on this first use initialisation.

You can typeset a math list into a box and discard it to get things started:

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
%\setmathfont{texgyrepagella-math}
%\setmathfont{STIXTwoMath-Regular.otf}
%\setmathfont{STIX2Math}
\setmathfont{latinmodern-math}
\begin{document}

\sbox0{$$}

\Umathfractionnumup\textstyle=10pt
\Umathfractiondenomdown\textstyle=10pt
\Umathfractionnumvgap\textstyle=10pt
\Umathfractiondenomvgap\textstyle=10pt
\Umathfractionnumup\displaystyle=10pt
\Umathfractiondenomdown\displaystyle=10pt
\Umathfractionnumvgap\displaystyle=10pt
\Umathfractiondenomvgap\displaystyle=10pt


Texstyle $\frac12$

displaystyle
$$\frac12$$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks, you are right. Now it is good. But this mean that it is not possible to insert in the preamble as default setting?

Comment: @BrunoGuizzon currently (there are some issues complaining about it:-) unicode-math does almost all its setup `\AtBeginDocument` so if you want to over-ride it in the preamble you almost always need to `\AtBeginDocument{...}` around the code so that it comes later, but that is usually enough.

Comment: Yes. It's OK. Many thanks again.